# Android fragment XML layout issue

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-fragments, fragment

I'm trying to achieve what I though would be a reasonably straightforward fragment layout, but I'm having some problems. Can anyone suggest the XML solution, roughly, for the following layout (I'm aware that there is now support for nested fragments, but I'd like to avoid this if possible):

"============================="
| 111111111111111111 | 333333333 |
| 111111111111111111 | 333333333 |
| 111111111111111111 | 333333333 |
| 111111111111111111 | 333333333 |
| 111111111111111111 | 333333333 |
| 111111111111111111 | 333333333 |
| ================== | 333333333 |
| 222222222222222222 | 333333333 |
| 222222222222222222 | 333333333 |
"============================="

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is indeed a simple layout.

Is this what you are looking for?

[image]

The code would be the following:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ff0000" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="#00ff00" >
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="#0000ff" >
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: 2 levels in the hierarchy is just a waste of resources and performances!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but after reading http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/22/android-layout-tricks-1/ I tend to agree with the previous comment. I'd like to keep performance as snappy as possible. I've never used TableLayout before, but I'm going to take a look at it to see if it'll do what I need.

Comment: @user1003815 The linked article suggests a RelativeLayout as the solution. That might indeed be the better solution in terms of performance. However, note that you cannot use `android:layout_weight` with RelativeLayouts. You have to use fixed heights/widths instead. I'm not sure if that's feasible for your fragment layout? Also: The performance benefit with a RelativeLayout will be much more important when you use such a layout e.g. for every item in a ListView. For a simple fragment layout like yours this wouldn't make a big difference.

Comment: Yep, the lack of support for layout_weight in RelativeView is why I turned to TableLayout, but in the end I've just gone with the solution provided in this answer (with the FrameLayout's replaced with fragments).